# emmeans: compare treatment effect across two levels of a category

Tags: r, contrasts, lsmeans

I want to compare the difference between treatment and placebo across two levels of a factor, lets say gender. This, to answer the question whether there is a significant difference in treatment effect across the two levels of gender.

The input to `emmeans()` is a repeated measures `gls()` model with a biomarker as an outcome. The biomarker was measured over multiple visits.

Currently I use the following code:
`emmeans(gls.fit, specs = trt.vs.ctrl ~ TREATMENT|GENDER)`

This returns the treatment effect for each level of gender, but not the difference in effect.

I also tried:

`emm1 <- emmeans(gls.fit, ~ TREATMENT|GENDER)`

`con <- contrast(emm1, "pairwise", by = "TREATMENT", name = "GENDER")`

`contrast(con, "pairwise", by = "GENDER")`

The latter appears to give an estimate for the TREATMENT:GENDER interaction similar to the original `gls()` model averaged across visits. This confuses me, because I though the gls coefficient only looks at the interaction, as it returns separate coefficients for all the visits.

What is the correct approach? I can calculate the difference manually using the first approach and the standard errors, but this is kinda cumbersome and doesn't give a p-value. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to determine if treatment varies along the levels of gender, put treatment * gender interaction in your model and read off the associated p-value.

Comment: Look at `vignette("interactions", "emmeans")`

Comment: @RussLenth: thank you, extensive documentation. I think my problem is at least partly due to incomplete understanding of `gls()` and its output.

Comment: Interpreting regression coefficients can sometimes help, but with more than one factor, it's often too confusing to do much good. I suggest first plotting what the model predicts (e.g., via emmip()), then testing what comparisons or interaction contrasts are suggested.

Comment: Testing interactions suggested by a plot... my p-hack radar is going off.

Comment: @JTH Mine too, even as I was writing that. But there's always the Scheffe adjustment. And sometimes, if you're really in the dark, you have to concede that this study is just exploratory. Yes, I was careless in suggesting that.